# Database design: storing full transaction history AND quick lookup of current status?

Tags: mysql, database-design, django-models

This is a pretty basic question, I'm a beginner :)

I'm building a library database using Django & MySQL. The database has the concepts of **books** and **users**, and of **transactions**, where a user takes out or returns a book.

I need to be able to:

- get the full list of transactions for a particular book - who checked it out and when
- get the current status of a book, quickly.

I had thought of using tables like this, but are there problems with this design?

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
TRANSACTION_TYPES = (
    ('I', 'Check in'),
    ('O', 'Check out'),
)
class Transaction(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TRANSACTION_CHOICES)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This would work OK for getting the full list of transactions. But if I want to get the current status of a book, I'd have to search through all the book's transactions and find the most recent.

Is this sensible? Is it future-proof?

I don't foresee the database getting that big, but is there a more efficient way to store the current status of a book, without de-normalising the database?

All suggestions gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A well-designed database won't search through all the book's transactions to find the most recent. At the very least, the database designer will create indexes, and the dbms will (probably) use them.

MySQL can do that; I'm not familiar enough with Django to know whether it's smart enough to get MySQL to do that. I'd be a little surprised if it weren't, though.

As to whether it's sensible and future proof--from my local library I've checked out out books, CDs (of both music and books), cassette tapes, maps, DVDs, video games, educational software, toys, and framed artwork.